# Start new thread using parameter in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create a new thread using parametrized thread in c#.

`rulehandler` is the object of the class

```
Thread applyPolicyThread = new Thread(
       new ParameterizedThreadStart(rulehandler.ApplyPolicy));
applyPolicyThread.start(false);
```

It is giving error that no overload method for apply policy matches delegates system.threading.start

Comment: Can you show the signature of `rulehandler.ApplyPolicy`? Based on what little I can deduce from the code posted it should look like `void ApplyPolicy(object p)`.

Comment: public void ApplyPolicy(bool isNewPolicy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter type for parametrized threads must always be `object` (see [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)):

```
public void ApplyPolicy(object param)
{
    bool value = (bool)param;
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you were talking about ApplyPolicy itself. You're right then, so +1 ;)

Comment: Kind of "old school" nowadays, if I may. Unless you need the thread to start synchronously (but execute asynchronously, of course).

Comment: @Baboon: Yes, I agree in most cases, but it was the answer to the question, why there is an exception. IMO threads should be used for something which runs "always" in the background (like a TcpListner of a server) and a `Task` should be used for "short" background tasks (which I think it is in this case)...

Comment: Indeed it does answer his question ;)
However Tasks can be used for long running asynchronous operations, you should then specify `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. For short operations, isn't `BackgroundWorker` recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the TPL:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() 
   => 
   {
      //This is executed in a separate thread
      ruleHandler.ApplyPolicy(false))
   });
```

This will start a new thread at the system's convenience (not instantly, but shortly after).
It allows you to pass strongly typed parameters.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll elaborate.

Comment: Please define it a little bit about Task.Factory.StartNew()

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use ParameterizedThreadStart.
You need to pass a method as an argument like this:

```
Thread applyPolicyThread = new Thread(
       new ParameterizedThreadStart(Start));
applyPolicyThread.start(false);
```

Where Start is a method like this

```
   static void Start(object info)
    {
    // This receives the value passed into the Thread.Start method.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `rulehandler.ApplyPolicy` is, but you're supposed to pass a method with `object` as the single argument (you can cast it inside):

```
void ApplyPolicy(object someState)
{
   bool boolState = (bool)someState;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by creating a no argument method as a target for the threadstart() and from that no argument method you can call your actual method with parameters.